# Ошибка при установке Parcel

Tags: npm

Подскажите пожалуйста - при установке Parcel командой: `npm i parcel-bundler --save-dev`, получаю стэк ошибок:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Frolov\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\21\e7\b75ba9f55f4831b06e62a1a213734228ec80124e1f5b8af1fda48c747cb39af3473ca95064f862cee32495f4969c9191a0b6928febe373f927de384d23d3
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@parcel%2ffs: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Frolov\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\21\e7\b75ba9f55f4831b06e62a1a213734228ec80124e1f5b8af1fda48c747cb39af3473ca95064f862cee32495f4969c9191a0b6928febe373f927de384d23d3'        
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Frolov\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-10T05_04_17_954Z-debug-0.log
```